# FTSearch and NotesDocumentCollection

Tags: search, collections, xpages

I am having problems doing FTsearch for field values from a notesdocumentcollection

if I go to the view "people" in the notesclient and do a search for FIELD DEPARTMENT = "Finance" I get back several results.

..and when I print out the query in on the web it is exactly the same as when I enter it in the client: FIELD DEPARTMENT = "Finance" but still no result is retrieved.

```
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.getView("people").getAllDocumentsByKey("people",true);

q = "\"" + r + "\""
query = "FIELD DEPARTMENT Contains " + q
dc.FTSearch(query);
```

also tried this

```
query = "[DEPARTMENT] Contains \"" + r + "\"";
dc.FTSearch(query);
```

if I return "dc" without the search i get several results

My queries seem to work for view.FTSearch  and db.FTSearch but not dc.FTSearch.

any ideas?

Comment: Is dc.FTSearch(query) actually running anything? I've found from bitter experience that if SSJS methods aren't correct the code just bombs out at that point and does not even throw an error. If you put the code in a button, with print or log statements around dc.FTSearch, does it run the following line's code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, it works now. not sure it was because I added "return" or if it was that I added a new return line. the lines below works

```
var dc:NotesDocumentCollection = database.getView("people").getAllDocumentsByKey("people",true);

query = "[DEPARTMENT] Contains \"" + r + "\"";
dc.FTSearch(query);
return dc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I fell into the same trap: you MUST use the 2nd parameter of FTSearch, e.g.

```
dc.FTSearch(query, 0)
```